# Calling an inherited method causes warning without cast to superclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, casting, compiler-warnings

I have the following inheritance tree:

```
NSObject <- GameObject <- RenderableObject <- SimpleBullet
```

`GameObject` has a method called `bounds` that returns the object's bounds. In my code I have a `SimpleBullet` that calls `bounds` to get its bounds, and I receive a warning saying `bounds` is defined in several places; odd. If I cast the `SimpleBullet` to a `GameObject` and call the `bounds` method, everything works as expected. What's happening? I can't figure out this behaviour. Example:

```
SimpleBullet* bullet = bulletInstance;
[bullet bounds];    // we get the warning.
[(GameObject*)bullet bounds];    // works as expected.
```

As I said, the `bounds` method is defined in `GameObject`, but why is Obj-C not aware that `SimpleBullet` is a `GameObject` and not allowing me to call its method without the warning?

Comment: Are you sure your compiler knows that `bullet` is a `SimpleBullet` object and not an `id` variable? When you call methods on `id` variables, the compiler can get confused.

Comment: Could you show a little more code? What is the **exact** error message, and where exactly does it happen? Show more code. Note that in ObjC, message sending is not bound to a class hierarchy, and that is probably why you get the warning, if there is another class that responds to that selector too.

Comment: As a sanity check, I just created a simple test following your description precisely and it works fine. Can you give a minimal test case (with actual code that you've run and seen the error with, not pseudocode) that actually exhibits the problem?

Comment: I'm at work right now. I will post the code this evening. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: If you can the [bullet bounds] with SimpleBullet instead of GameObject, is there the warning yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I managed to know what was happening. The compiler was playing tricks on me because did not report a meanfull error. The problem was that  I wasn't importing/including SimpleBullet.h. A forward declaration was declared but not the real implementation.

This, leads me to think that by default compiler treats it as an id object, and tries to find a method among all registered classes that suits the call signature. Just a guess, not sure about this :).

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Here's what went wrong: If you just forward-declare a class, the compiler doesn't know anything except that it exists. In particular, the compiler doesn't know what its superclass is or what methods it implements. Forward declaration is primarily meant to help you break circular imports; it's not a perfect substitute for actually importing the file.

Comment: Yes, of course, I know how forwarding works and uses. What I really wonder is why the compiler did not reporte an error like "Class not found/defined", "Unknown symbol", "Can't find class implementation" or something like this when using SimpleBullet class instead of the criptic error it was providing. This is why I was trying to guess what was hapenning.

Answer (score 1):

`UIView` also has a `-bounds` method.  Make sure your method has the same return type.

Comment: Yes. UIView has a bounds method too. But SimpleBullet has nothing to do with UIView. So, don't see why the compiler is complaining about it. I mean, they are not related in any way in the inheritance tree. And the weird thing is that casting to GameObject* (the class where the bounds method resides) the warning disappears :/. Why is not the compiler still complaining about having a boudns method in UIView?.

Comment: This shouldn't matter as long as everything is typed correctly.